# Como mostrar correctamente el estilo de Bootstrap en DataTables?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, angular-datatables

El estilo no se aplica correctamente en mi pagina, estoy seguro del orden al que le di a los estilos **CSS** y **scripts**. Pero aun asi me siguen sin funcionar aun cuando me base en los mismos ejemplos de la pagina de Angular-Datatables.

Como pueden notar en la imagen, el `TextBox` y la paginacion deberían tener un formato basado en los estilos de [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap), pero no es el caso, se despliegan como cualquier etiqueta [html](/questions/tagged/html) sin estilo.

[image: imagen]

Si se necesita mas información al respecto del sitio para solucionar el problema o se me olvidaron detalles importantes por favor díganmelo para solucionar el problema mas rápido.

XP Quick Claims

```
        <!--CSS-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/angular-datatables/angular-datatables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div ng-include  src="'app/components/navbar/navbar.view.html'"></div>
    <div class="container" ng-view></div>


    <!--Tables-->
    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/ngMask/dist/ngMask.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>     
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/bootstrap/angular-datatables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Módulo-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/filtros/filters.module.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/filtros/filter.input.module.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/navbar/navbar.module.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/usuarios/usuario.module.login.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/usuarios/usuarios.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/pacientes/pacientes.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/aseguradora/aseguradora.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/components/pdf/pdf.module.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: El enlace a la imagen está roto y deberías formatear el código mejor. También sería conveniente si añadieras el código que genera (y el generado) los datatables

Comment: Hola yo tenia el mismo error con los estilos de bootstrap lo que hice fue copiar la cdn que tiene la pagina de ejemplo de datatables puedes encontrar los cdn en el codigo del ejemplo espero haberte ayudado ^^ https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap-simple.html

Comment: No tendrás choques en algunas clases dentro de los estilos?

Comment: Mira estas guias, donde indica que y como utilizarlas.<br>
Para Bootstrap3: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html <br>
Para BootStrap4: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html
<br><br>
Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Nuevamente, ahora le voy a dar el ejemplo para este caso :D 
https://gitlab.com/erikrs921/boostrap-data-table-exampl

En resumen el codigo aqui abajo, pero tienes que descargarte las fuentes del enlace que te dejo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bootstrap-table').bdt({
    showSearchForm: 0,
    showEntriesPerPageField: 0
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Based-Data-Table-Bootstrap-Data-Table/js/jquery.bdt.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Based-Data-Table-Bootstrap-Data-Table/css/jquery.bdt.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="box clearfix">
        <h3>Bootstrap Data Table</h3>
        <p>Easily turn your tables into datatables.</p>

        <table class="table table-hover" id="bootstrap-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#ID</th>
              <th>Username</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
            </tr>
            .....................
            <td>190</td>
            <td>johndoe</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 53,
  "colno": 11
}

Comment: " Jorge Luis Alcantara". Si lo ejecutas aqui, no va a cargar. Solo puse parte del codigo, necesitas descargarte la fuente completa.

Comment: @ErikRoky hey, gracias por agregar un ejemplo, hay que desarrollar un poco las respuestas, no solo añadir enlaces, (revisar [answer]), esto para que la información que compartes sea de utilidad para muchos desarrolladores, gracias y saludos!

Comment: @ErikRoky he editado tu respuesta para que el codigo se pueda ejecutar aqui